# Processor Affinity .Net application pool

Tags: .net, iis-7, application-pool

I have read the processor affinity section of the application pool in technet and got somewhat confused.

I have a quad core azure server for testing. I would like to set an application pool to one of the cores as its a naughty service that gobbles up CPU resource.

How do i work out the value to put in the affinity field on IIS 7/Windows2008r2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit field, where each bit corresponds to one processor, starting with least significant bit.

If you want the affinity to just one of your four processor, set the value to either 1, 2, 4 or 8.
For affinity to more processors, add these values together as needed.

Comment: Does this hold on multicore cpus? If i put 1 into affinity is that setting the application pool to 1 core or the one cpu i have?

Comment: Each "processor" we are talking here about, is whatever appears to the operating system as capable of executing an instruction stream on the given computer independently. So if you have e.g. 4 CPUs (=the physical pieces that fit into the socket on the motherboard), each with 2 cores, then you have 8 processors for the purpose of the processor affinity. Same thing as you see in the Task Manager -> Performance.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer; its strange that MS' documentation on this is so week. Brink on windows 2012 in production so i can throttle to a %